# defining and updating coordinates with pascal

Tags: variables, pascal

this is PASCAL;

I have numeorus rectangles which are defined by their top right and bottom left corner coordinates like (x1,y1,x2,y2). i have to shift these coordinates by variables a and b  (x1+a,y1+b,x2+a,y2+b).

is there an easy way to define these constants and then shift them? I am doing this by one by and it takes a long time. pls dont tell me to use "some concept or command" give an example code if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your compiler, but in active versions of Pascal (Delphi or FPC), if you have the rectangles in a TRect named *rect*, you can simply do

```
OffsetRect(rect,a,b);
```

you might need to add unit "types" to your uses clause though